# On nginx, Are those two server setting equal things?

Tags: nginx

I have settings to `www` rewrite or return.

**1:**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

**2:**

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    example.com;
    return         301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}
```

Are these two things equal?

It seems to be working well, but I can't have assurance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which `server` block is the *default server* for port 80.

If this `server` block is also the *implicit* default server for port 80, it may need to handle requests for server names other than `example.com`, in which case the value of `$host` will not be equal to the value of `$server_name`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) for more.

You could use `$server_name` instead of `$host`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_server_name) for details.